# How do I put an object in the middle of an object?

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode

I have been quite wondering for sometime now on how to do this; here is a reference image:

[image]

Basically the yellow point or circle should move to the 2nd arrow moving to the center of the red circle. I'd want something like that on blender.

Anything is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Assuming the origins of both meshes are at their centres, select the red circle in Object mode and then use SHIFT-S > Cursor to Selected. Then select your yellow object and Shift-S > Selected to Cursor. Job done!

Comment: ... or select the yellow object first, then the red object (selected last=active), and use *Shift+S > Selected to Active*

Comment: ... or if the origins are not centred, go to Object>Set Origin>Geometry to Origin/Origin to geometry or whatever you want.

Comment: ...or if you don't want to change the origin, but the origin isn't in center: select the mesh in edit mode -> Shift+S-> Cursor to selected, then in object mode select your other object -> shift +s -> selection to cursor

Comment: That lot should keep him busy deciding which to use! :^))

Comment: Your solution has already worked @JohnEason, mind making an answer? and I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Sure, although the other answers are just as good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the origins of both meshes are at their centres, select the red circle in <kbd>Object</kbd> mode and then use <kbd>SHIFT-S</kbd> > <kbd>Cursor to Selected</kbd>. Then select your yellow object and <kbd>Shift-S</kbd> > <kbd>Selected to Cursor</kbd>.